# Show notification to Users on ribbon button click

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, exceljs, ribbonx

I have a excel add-in and which adds some buttons to Ribbon bar. On click of one of these buttons, I need to apply some validation on value of active cell and show notification to user, if data validation fails. First part of data validation is straight forward, however I am unable to find some class/function in Office/Excel Js API, which can show notification o user. Is there any simple way to show notifications to users?

Answer (score 1):

The standard action of a ribbon button is to open a task pane. On the task pane you can host any content like a notification and do any extra stuff. You can read more about ribbon commands in Office web add-ins in the [Add-in commands for Excel, PowerPoint, and Word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands#command-capabilities) article.,

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using a task pane as @EugeneAstafiev has suggested, you could have the code in the function command branch when the value is invalid and display a dialog with the [Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

Comment: I am trying to use Dialog to show error message, however I cannot reduce height of dialog from a certain minimum value and there is white space of 3-4 lines below my error message and client is not accepting it. I cannot increase font-size to cover this space.

Comment: What happens when you increase the font size?

Comment: user requirement to use same font size on all pages/dialogs